# DENSE_RANK on two columns, where one column are distinct values and the other has duplicate

Tags: sql-server, sum, window-functions, dense-rank

I have the following scenario where I'm struggling to understand how to apply `DENSE_RANK()` to get the result I want:

| ID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990-05-17 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1991-10-12 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1992-08-01 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1993-07-05 | 0.67 |
| 1 | 1994-05-02 | 0.67 |
| 1 | 1995-02-01 | 1.00 |
| 1 | 1996-03-01 | 1.00 |

Based on the above data, I'm trying to identify distinct periods using the combination of the `Date` and `Value` columns, where a unique period is identified from where the `Value` column changes from one value to another. Here's the result I'm looking for:

| ID | Date | Value | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990-05-17 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1991-10-12 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1992-08-01 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1993-07-05 | 0.67 | 2 |
| 1 | 1994-05-02 | 0.67 | 2 |
| 1 | 1995-02-01 | 1.00 | 3 |
| 1 | 1996-03-01 | 1.00 | 3 |

As you can see, there are 3 distinct periods. The problem I am having is that when I use `DENSE_RANK()`, I get one of two outcomes:

`SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date, Value)`

| ID | Date | Value | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990-05-17 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1991-10-12 | 1.00 | 2 |
| 1 | 1992-08-01 | 1.00 | 3 |
| 1 | 1993-07-05 | 0.67 | 4 |
| 1 | 1994-05-02 | 0.67 | 5 |
| 1 | 1995-02-01 | 1.00 | 6 |
| 1 | 1996-03-01 | 1.00 | 7 |

`SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value)`

| ID | Date | Value | Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990-05-17 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1991-10-12 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1992-08-01 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1993-07-05 | 0.67 | 2 |
| 1 | 1994-05-02 | 0.67 | 2 |
| 1 | 1995-02-01 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1996-03-01 | 1.00 | 1 |

As you can see, the problem lies with the `Date` column as I need that to be a cumulative period. Furthermore, the amount of periods will vary from `ID` to `ID` and there's no consistent science behind the `Date` column. A member could have two entries in one year for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` window function to get for each row its previous Value and with conditional aggregation with `SUM()` window function get the `Periods`:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Value,
       SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = prev_value THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) Period 
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) prev_value
  FROM tablename
) t
ORDER BY Date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73bc2fcb4a897f61b62f5767d3fe5ce9).

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a gaps and island problem. One method is to use a couple of `ROW_NUMBER`s to put your data into groups:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [date],[value])-
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, [value] ORDER BY [date]) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(1,CONVERT(date,'1990-05-17'),1.00),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'1991-10-12'),1.00),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'1992-08-01'),1.00),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'1993-07-05'),0.67),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'1994-05-02'),0.67),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'1995-02-01'),1.00),
                (1,CONVERT(date,'1996-03-01'),1.00))V(ID,Date,Value))
SELECT ID,
       Date,
       Value,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Grp) AS Period
FROM CTE;
```